# Twilio video sends me an error (NotReadableError: could not start video source) on my android-chrome browser (reactJS app)

Tags: android, reactjs, video, twilio

I have a nodeJS / reactJS app using twilio-video 2.1.0.

It works great, exept when I try to login via my chrome app on my smartphone (android) and someone got the same issue on a window tab (I don't know which browser).

The issue sent is "NotReadableError: could not start video source".

From what I read, this is because another app or something is using the camera. But even after rebooting the phone it doesnt work. Don't know what to do now (still digging in the api doc).

I found someone saying :

```
if(this.lastStream) {
  this.lastStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop()) 
}
```

fixed his issue. Though my page have no running stream I would guess ...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an https issue, works only in local and https.

Comment: how did you solve the problem? It works on http or not